# How to properly deploy PowerShell core Zip on Windows

Tags: powershell

The following link provides two options to install PWSH on windows, MSI, and Zip:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.2

How to properly install the zip package? It includes all the required files, but it needs to be added to PATH and do some windows registry updates, to my understanding.

Is there a list of steps or instructions that explains how to deploy PowerShell core properly on windows using zip package?

Comment: Have you tried to just run the "pwsh.exe" from the ZIP?

Comment: I expect it worked. But the question is how to "properly" do it. Include explorer integration, registry updates etc.

Comment: If there is no official documentation you could have a look at the [source of the Windows Installer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/d7370cfa44153a519c28b0401d3a93d1d4aced9a/assets/wix) and see which registry keys it creates etc. May I ask why you can't use the MSI?